# Proving an inequality with $\arcsin$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

So  i have a problem proving this inequality:
for any $$x\in \left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right); |\arcsin(2x)-\arcsin(x)|\leq \frac{|x|}{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}$$

May initial idea was to use either Rolle's either Lagrange's theorem, but i don't know how to apply any of them, i also thought of using derivatives but it was a long shot.
Any help would really be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: my mistake in the title, it's arcsin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall the **mean value theorem** for a continuously differentiable function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$:
We have $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(\xi)$$
for some $\xi \in (a,b)$. In your example, take $f(t)=\arcsin(t)$ (which exists and is continuously differentiable on $(-1,1)$ by the inverse function theorem), and $[a,b]=[x,2x] \subset (-1,1)$.
For simplicity choose $x>0$.

Then $$f'(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}$$

And hence we have $$\arcsin(2x)-\arcsin(x)=x\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\xi^{2}}}$$
for some $\xi \in (x,2x)$. The RHS is increasing as a function of $\xi$ for $\xi>0$, so the RHS is bounded above by the quantity $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-(2x)^{2}}}$; done.

There is some fiddling with whether $x$ is positive or negative to get the modulus signs, but I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**. From the identity,
$$
\arcsin x=\int_0^x\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}},\quad |x|<1,
$$ one gets, for $|x|<\dfrac12$,
$$
|\arcsin 2x-\arcsin x|=\left|\int_x^{2x}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\right|\le\frac{\left|\int_x^{2x}dt\right|}{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}=\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}.
$$

Comment: How did you get that integral inequality? Beautiful answer.

Comment: Observe that $t \mapsto \frac1{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$ is increasing over $[x,2x]$, then use $\left|\int_a^bf(x)dx\right |\le M\left|b-a\right|$, here one can take $M=|f(b)|$. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct. Note that from Lagrange's theorem, you get for a function $f$ that is continuous in $[a,b]$, differentiable in $(a,b)$, there exists a point $c \in [a,b]$ such that

$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = f'(c)$$

Note that here $f(x)=\arcsin x$ is monotone increasing in $(-1/2,1/2)$.

Let $a=x$, $b=2x$. If $x>0$, then $b>a$.
Therefore 
$$\frac{f(2x)-f(x)}{x} = f'(c)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}$$
Last step is because $c\leq b=2x$.
Now handle the $x<0$ case in a similar manner to complete the result.

Answer (score 1):

As the functions under the absolute values are odd, you can restrict the domain to $(0,\frac12)$.

The inequality obviously holds when $x=0$. Then taking the derivative

$$\arcsin 2x-\arcsin x\le\frac x{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}$$ becomes

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}-\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}+\frac{4x^2}{(1-4x^2)^{3/2}}\\
=\frac1{(1-4x^2)^{3/2}}$$ or

$$\frac{1-8x^2}{(1-4x^2)^{3/2}}\le\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$

This is obviously true when $x\ge\dfrac1{\sqrt8}=\sqrt{\dfrac4{32}}$, and by reworking,

$$(1-8x^2)^2(1-x^2)\le(1-4x^2)^3,$$

$$5x^2-32x^4=x^2(5-32x^2)\ge0.$$

true whenever $$x\le \sqrt{\frac5{32}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that helps illustrate why you should believe the result to be true in the first place. As @Yves did, I'll restrict attention to $u \geq 0$ (where I'm using $u$ instead of $x$).

[image]

In the figure,

$$\theta := \angle TOV^\prime - \angle SOV^\prime = \operatorname{asin}2u - \operatorname{asin} u$$

Since, $\triangle OTU^\prime \sim \triangle V^\prime OT$, we have
$$\frac{2u}{\sqrt{1-4u^2}} = \frac{2v}{1}\qquad\to\qquad
\frac{u}{\sqrt{1-4u^2}} = v = |\overline{TV}| \geq |\overline{TZ}| \geq |\stackrel{\frown}{TS}|$$

The final inequality is precisely the statement that, for First-Quadrant angles $\theta$,
$$\tan \theta \geq \theta$$
whose proof was probably one of your earliest Calculus exercises. $\square$